# why is "wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" is not working in scrapping and "wikitable sortable" is working?

Tags: python, jquery, web-scraping

I was trying to scrap the first table from

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_the_United_States_by_revenue`

But i was stuck as i was not getting the html content for the 'table' tab with the class = "wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter", i went on with using just find_all(table)[1] and got the output.

This class was bothering me so i just removed the "jquery-tablesorter" and i got the expected data.

My question is what is "jquery-tablesorter" in the class name doing and its role and could anyone help me explain what are the best practice for scrapping using BeautifulSoup if i come across same kind of Issue.

Note:- i am new to scrapping and working on sorting out all questions regarding scrapping.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `wikitable sortable` instead of `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` because when you first load the page, the table might not be initially formatted or sorted until the JavaScript code runs and initializes the sorting functionality. This is a common technique to improve page load performance by allowing the initial rendering without sorting.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_the_United_States_by_revenue'
req = requests.get(link)
soup = bs(req.content, 'html5lib')

table = soup.findAll('table', attrs = {'class':'wikitable sortable'})
print(table[0])
```

Length of table is 3, but you want first table, so table[0]